# Different format for datagridview cell in edit mode

Tags: winforms, formatting, datagridviewcolumn, editmode

I have a text datagridviewcolumn displaying an integer.
I set the format property to `colTextDefaultCellStyle.Format = "#,##0";`.

So the number that is displayed gets a thousand separator.

When in edit mode I do not want to show the thousand separator.
But I cannot figure out how to do it. This e.g. doesn't work:

```
void dgv_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCell cell = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

    if (e.ColumnIndex == colText.Index)
    {
        if (cell.IsInEditMode) cell.Style.Format = "";
        else cell.Style.Format = "#,##0";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply the actual formatting and then set `e.FormattingApplied` to True.

```
void dgv_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == colText.Index)
    {
        DataGridViewCell cell = dgv.Item[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];

        if (cell.IsInEditMode)
        {
            e.Value = e.Value.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            e.Value = e.Value.ToString("#,##0");
        }
        e.FormattingApplied = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: the `e.FormattingApplied = true;` is not necessary in my case

Comment: also because e.Value is an object `double` in my case the value must be cast/converted to double for the method `ToString("#,##0")` to be available