# How to set DataGridView cell formatting

Tags: winforms, datagridview, format, cell

I have a winform with a datagridview.
I read a text file as data for the datagridview and in two columns I have values as 6.5
But when I enter the value 7,5 it changes it to 75.

How do I fix this so when I enter 7,5 it should change to 7.5.
If I enter 7.5 it works just fine.

B.t.w I'am from Denmark if that could help. :)

I tried to replace comma with dot in CellEndEdit and CellLeave

I tried this code.

```
DataGridViewTextBoxCell cell = DataGridViewTextBoxCell)

cell.Value = cell.FormattedValue.ToString().Replace(",",".);
```

But that did absolutely nothing.

Comment: I assume the Value has already been formatted by the time you set the value. Not sure, but maybe the datagrid has a CultureInfo object which you can set.

Comment: I cannot find any CultureInfo in the datagrid.
The format for the cells are set to N2, like this

`private void dgvVCOData_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
 e.CellStyle.Format = "N2";
}`

Comment: Check this answer out to see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26307017/1623971

Comment: Did not help. :(

Comment: What is the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` set to in your application? Is it localizable? -- To make it clear, do you want to present the data formatted using the InvariantCulture, but you want to enter / edit the data in any other format (or the Format of a specific Culture)? -- BTW, the general Cell's Style Format is not set in `CellFormatting`, it's usually set in the corresponding DataGridViewColumn's `Format` property, unless you want to generate a very specific format that cannot be set in the Property

Comment: I just want to change the value from 7,5 to 7.5 if the user enters 7,5 to avoid wrong numbers.

The culture is:
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

I'm from Denmark but the app is in english.

Comment: I tried to change the format on DefaultCellStyle to #,0.0, that display the values fine when I load. But if I double click in a cell and enter 7,5 it writes 75 when I leave the cell.

Comment: I just tried this code.

`private void dgvVCOData_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
 string cellValue = dgvVCOData.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].FormattedValue.ToString();
 if (cellValue.Contains(','))
 {
  dgvVCOData.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = cellValue.ToString().Replace(",",".");
 }
}`

But the cell value already has the value 75 at this point.

Comment: It's the User that has to follow the number format rules, not your app. If the User enters `7,543`, is that meant to be `7543` or `7.543`? How do you know what format the User wanted to refer to? Your app needs to provide constant / predictable behavior -- Maybe add a reminder that the number format rule follows the Invariant Culture (British? Imperial?), or your app has means to select the Culture, i.e., it's localizable

Comment: The number must be 7.543
I just want to avoid wrong numbers.
You never know what the user will enter.

I can tell them to use x.x but I pretty sure at some point the will enter x,x

It for validating the user input.

Comment: Your question is really about how to customize the parsing of text entered into the cell.  The DGV provides the [DataGridView.CellParsing Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellparsing?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#examples) to allow for custom parsing.